# Oracle->MSSQL: How to set identifier generator?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm migrating OracleDB11g to MSSQL2014.

Currently getting following error when trying to save new data:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot
>   insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'testDB.FILE_SETTINGS';
>   column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

My interpretation is that this is caused as the "native" ID generator differs between Oracle & MSSQL (Sequence vs. Identity).

In Oracle we had small customization to HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE:

```
alter sequence hibernate_sequence increment by 5;
```

...but thats all.

hibernate-mapping is originally like this:

```
<id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long">
    <generator class="native">
    </generator>
</id>
```

In MSSQL I have tried it like this with no luck:

```
<id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long">
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

And in MSSQL server I have sequence (migration tool created):

> HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE in testDB->Views->sys.sequences

Also found in (migration tool created):

> testDB->Views->INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES

How should this be done properly as I want to retain the same way to generate identity as was in Oracle? Something wrong in MSSQL or in hibernate settings?

Hibernate version is quite old: 2.1.8

Comment: Found out that the hibernate 2.1.8 does not support SQL dialect which would support SEQUENCE in MSSQL. I think SQL Server 2012 is the first version to support sequence so hibernate needs an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question if some day someone has similar issues:

Apparently there was nothing wrong with the settings I mentioned in original question, only that hibernate 2.1.8 seemed not to support the SEQUENCE id genererator. Also old hibernate obviously did not support the needed SQLServer2012Dialect.

Ended up updating the hibernate version to 4.3.11 (with its dependencies). This version got selected as it required the least amount of refactoring.

I had some issues with the dependencies as this old project was not using Maven.

Also faced this error as any DB query was attempted:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I found out that new hibernate version was defaulted to use lazy loading which was not supported in the old version. So I ended up fixing it with setting "lazy=false" in hibernate setting files.

> You may see "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session" while upgrading from hibernate 2.1 to hibernate 3.0. You will suddenly find yourself puzzling what happened, it was working before update. Reasons is, Hibernate 3 introduced lazy loading as the default i.e. lazy="true". If you want it to work the same as before you can mark everything as lazy="false". Alternatively you'll have to start eagerly initialising your entities and associations.
>
> Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/04/orghibernatelazyinitializationException-Could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-hibernate-java.html#ixzz56ahBmiBl

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the error is wrong. This error tells you nothing about `sequence`. It tells you that your `testDB.FILE_SETTINGS` has `id` column defined as `NOT NULL` but you try to insert `NULL` value here.

I don't see your code but I think there is something like this:

```
create table dbo.MyTbl_wrong (id int NOT NULL, col1 varchar(100) );
insert into dbo.MyTbl_wrong(col1) values ('1 str'), ('2 str'), ('3 str');
```

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table
>   'db2.dbo.MyTbl_wrong'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

What you should do instead is to use `sequence` in the default for your `id` column like this:

```
create sequence dbo.MySeq 
start with 1;

create table dbo.MyTbl (id int NOT NULL default(next value for dbo.MySeq), col1 varchar(100) );

insert into dbo.MyTbl(col1) values ('1 str'), ('2 str'), ('3 str');

--select *
--from dbo.MyTbl;
-------
--id    col1
--1 1 str
--2 2 str
--3 3 str
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the error message is not directly about the sequence. You are suggesting I would do the "work" in SQL, isn't it just quick&dirty solution for what I am trying to achieve using Hibernate annotations/config in Java code?

Comment: >>>for what I am trying to achieve using Hibernate annotations/config in Java code<<< I have no idea about "Hibernate annotations/config in Java code", all I said is what is the cause of your error. YOU ARE TRYING TO INSERT NULL VALUE IN NOT NULLABLE COLUMN. Also, I don't know what exactly your code does, the only thing I can say it's not SEQUENCE to cause your error. I just showed you how the correct code should look like: the correct use of sequence does not cause this error